# Overlay questions on MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mkmapview, cllocation

I have setup a `CLLocation` object, I am adding `MKCircle` overlay. I want the `radius` variable of the `MKCircle` to be relative to two this:

1. The size of the Map View
2. The size of the location

So, how can I retrieve some sort of size value from a `CLLocation`? And even better, would it automatically scale once I interact/zoom in out with the map view? Here is an overview of my objective:

Add an overlay to the map view. The overlay will be at a `CLLocation` `CLLocationCoordinate2D` variable, but I want that overlay to fit the size of that location and then resize once I zoom in and out with the map, which I am pretty sure it should do automatically. I know that I need to define the `MKCircle`'s radius variable, but then how should I set it? So, do you guys know how I can do this?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
CLLocation *org = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordO.latitude longitude:coordO.longitude];
CLLocation *des = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordD.latitude longitude:coordD.longitude];

MKCircle *myCircle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coordO radius:org.horizontalAccuracy];
MKCircle *myCircle2 = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coordD radius:des.horizontalAccuracy];

if (myCircle2 && myCircle) {

    NSLog(@"destination and origin both valid");
}

[mapView addOverlays: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myCircle, myCircle2, nil]];

[myCircle setTitle:@"Placeholder"];
[myCircle2 setTitle:@"Placeholder"];

[localOverlays addObjectsFromArray: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myCircle, myCircle2, nil]];
```

This is all the code I use to add an overlay to the map view, although it does not work, the overlay (`MKCircle` which I presume is a circle) is not there/visible. I took a look at the HazardMap Apple Sample Code and it looks like they have created a few other classes for setup. Is this necessary, what is wrong with my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of a `MKCircle` is a `CLLocationDistance`, which represents a distance measurement in meters.
The horizontal accuracy of a `CLLocation` is `CLLocationAccuracy` which represents the accuracy of a coordinate value in meters.

So, all you need to do is:

```
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:location.coordinate
                                                 radius:location.horizontalAccuracy];
```

**UPDATE:** The overlays are not visible because you created the locations manually, so their horizontal accuracy is zero. You can create a `CLLocation` with a custom horizontal accuracy using the method `-[CLLocation initWithCoordinate:altitude:horizontalAccuracy:verticalAccuracy:timestamp:]`. Or you may define a minimum radius for the circles (for example 10 meters):

```
CLLocationDistance radius = MAX(10, location.horizontalAccuracy);
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, can I quickly ask you one question? I have some code that adds an MKCircle overlay shown in my updated answer. I would appreciate it if you answered it.